# I want to use images of products that I register in the database - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I programmed a product registration. The registration for the database is working correctly. My problem is that I can't show the images that I registered in the database. I created an imput where the name of the image is inserted. This name is saved in the database and the image is saved with the same name, however it is saval in public. The images are inside the public / storage / products folder.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{   
    $products = Product::paginate(10);

    return view('products.index', [
        'products' => $products,
    ]);
}


public function store(Request $request)
{   
    // Create registration 
    $data = $request->only('name', 'price', 'imageName');

    Product::create($data);

    
    // Image
    
    if($request->file('imageProduct')->isValid()){
        $nameFile = $request->imageName . '.' . $request->file('imageProduct')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('imageProduct')->storeAs('products', $nameFile);
        
        return redirect()->route('ProductControllerIndex');
    }

}
```

view:

```
 <div>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <p>
            Id: {{ $product->id }}
        </p>

        <p>
            Nome do produto: {{ $product->name }}
        </p>

        <p>
            Preço: {{ $product->price }}
        </p>

        <p>
           {{ $product->imageName }} 
        </p>

        <p>
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/products/'.$product->imageName) }}" alt="">
        </p>
        <hr>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: What does `$product->imageName` contain? Looking at your code, I feel like it's missing the extension, as you're calling `Product::create($data)`, which happens before `$request->file('imageProduct')->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: What doesn't work? No image? Wrong image? Does `{{ $product->imageName }}` show the correct name?

Comment: `$product->imageName` This takes the value of an input. It is an input to pass the name of the image and this name is saved in the database and the image receives that name.

Comment: Yup, but you're saving the file as `$request->imageName . {extension}`. In your database, you probably don't see any `.png`, `.jpg` etc extensions in your `imageName` column, do you? When referencing the image in a `src` attribute, **it needs the extension, or it will return a 404**

Comment: The orignal extension of the image is saved together with the name that is passed in the input

Comment: Do you want a print of the database?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt, or an output of `dd(asset('storage/products/'.$product->imageName))`. Not trying to be mean, but I don't see the logic in your code that saves the extension to the database :)

Comment: sorry, the extension is not being saved.

Comment: How can I pass the value of this variable (`$nameFile`) to be saved in the database?

Comment: Ah, so it's not. Ok, no worries, we can fix that :) Let me do a quick write-up for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up. It's just that I've been trying to do this for many hours and then I thought about doing it through the database and I didn't even realize if the extension was being saved.

Comment: Image uploads are a tricky thing to get right until you've done it a number of times. Trial and error is all good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue here is that your Image's extension is not being saved to the database, so `$product->imageName`, when used in the `asset()` helper, doesn't generate a complete URL for the image. You'll need to refactor your code a little to get it to save:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {   
    $nameFile = $request->input('imageName', '');
    if($request->file('imageProduct')->isValid()){
        $nameFile .= '.' . $request->file('imageProduct')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('imageProduct')->storeAs('products', $nameFile);
    }

    $request->merge(['imageName' => $nameFile]);
    $data = $request->only('name', 'price', 'imageName');

    Product::create($data);

    return redirect()->route('ProductControllerIndex');
}
```

In the above code, the value for `$nameFile` is defaulted to the value in `$request->input('imageName')`, or an empty string `''` if nothing is supplied. Next, if a valid image is uploaded, the `$nameFile` variable is appended with the extension. Lastly, the `$request` variable is updated with the name value for `imageName`. The remainder of the code creates the new `Product` with the data supplied (using the `->only()` modifier) and redirect as required.

The rest of your code should be ok, as long as the file exists in the correct directory after `->storeAs()` and the fully-qualified image name is saved to the database.

Note: If for whatever reason `Product::create()` doesn't work with this approach, you can use the `new Product()` ... `$product->save()` approach: (there might be an issue with `$request->merge()` using an existing key, as I can't actually test that)

```php
$product = new Product();

$product->name = $request->input('name');
$product->price = $request->input('price');
$product->imageName = $fileName;

$product->save();
```

Comment: Did not work :/. It was saved in the bank but not with the extension

Comment: Did you try with the secondary approach I noted?

Comment: Was. I had used form two but I forgot to take a snippet of the code. Vlw man, thank you very much, from the heart